# Application slower on qt 4.8.0 than 4.7.4

Tags: qt, qt4.7, qt4.8

I have an application that I was developing with Qt 4.7.4 but I had the problem (the bug is reported) with the button's (too small) hit area. So I change for Qt 4.8.0. Now my problem with the button is resolved, but my application runs really slower that it ran with Qt 4.7.4. Is there anything I need to do? Kind of settings...

Thanks

Comment: You're going to need to be way more specific as to what is running slower, whether you're running in debug mode, etc. The more information you give, the more likely it is someone can help you.

Comment: It's my all application that runs slower, every click, every display, everything take twice more time that it used to. Like if I was on an old computer. I'm talking about my application in the deployment form because I'm in the tests. I'm coding on Mac OSX Lion (10.7.4) with Qt 2.4.1

Comment: Have you tried to profile the application? I would use QElapsedTimer to measure what I see is slower and try to determine where the "extra time" is spent. This might be useful or not, depending on the results.

Comment: well, that could be useful for something that has few things to check, but the problem is that everything is slow just after the update, so it would be too long and not really useful for me to do that...but thanks...it could be useful one day